# MissingReferenceException for audio in Unity3D

Tags: javascript, audio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am calling a sound to be played with the variable being called as

```
var MySound : AudioSource;
```

and calling it in the update function under

```
if(Effect.current >= 20)
{
     MySound.Play();
}
```

I am using multiple audio sources for 4 different sounds, and for some reason, it says the variable does not exist when the sound is triggered. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: user simply forgot to drag the variable in the inspector